# how to get data in queue using GCD in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

```
for (int s=0; s<masterArray.count; s++) {

       for (int i=0; i<countOfSub1; i++) {

    }
}
```

vast amount of data in this loop so, i want get when s=0 then get all data of second loop then after s=1 then after get all data of second loop so on, then how can i set thread in this code.   Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand what you are asking for. Could you try to rephrase your question?

Comment: so you want to delegate all computation for `s=0` to a separate queue and keep the caller wait until it is done, before getting to the second iteration `s=1`?

Comment: @OzgurVatansever yes

Comment: I believe you are running this code on a main thread, so keeping it waiting at each iteration has lots of downsides in terms of performance. Just create a queue with only one thread and dispatch jobs that will be done in the inner loop to that queue asynchronously.

Comment: i already using main thread but problem is it take a some time to show data on view.

Comment: for example i have fifty horizontal scroll and i want get one by one scroll using thread so, how can i set this hierarchy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it by the following example

```
for (int s=0; s<masterArray.count; s++) {// your main loop starts here
dispatch_semaphore_t  sem;
sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

for (int i=0; i<countOfSub1; i++) {// Inner loop in a thread
//your work here
}
dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
});
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); // main loop waiting to be triggered from sub loop. (inner loop)
}
```

Comment: @Rock what is the problem with it?

Comment: as per your code   2017-04-26 16:17:40.848 DietPlan[4708:161628]  S : 0
  S : 1
  I : 0
  I : 0
  I : 1
  S : 2
 I : 1
  I : 2
 I : 2
 S : 3
  I : 0
 I : 3
 I : 3
 I : 1
  I : 4
this type of data disply

Comment: i want  s=0 then  i=0 up to i = countsub1.count  then s=1 then so, i=0 upto  i= countsub1.count so on...

Comment: can you please show me how you are using above code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142725/discussion-between-rock-and-syed-ali-salman).